# DatePicker ClosedRange in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker, swiftui-list

How do I set DatePicker in SwiftUI in such a way that the user cannot select a date and time from the past? They should be able to select dates and times from now and in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set range to DatePicker like this:

```
DatePicker("Please enter a date", selection: $wakeUp, in: Date.now...)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why the datePicker is printing the wrong date? its in 12 hour format.

Comment: @shana, that can be separate question, we need to be more specific here

Comment: Its ok. I figured it out. Thanks for responding.